# I can't create Java Stubs from proto file

Tags: java, xml, grpc, grpc-java, protobuf-java

I have a very simple proto file in the resources folder. Here is my `hello.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option java_package = "org.abraxel.grpc";

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
  rpc SayHelloAgain (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

When I want to generate the service classes from .proto file, the build install succeeds, but the classes are not created in the folder. My `pom.xml` file:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <grpc.version>1.47.0</grpc.version>
    <protoc.version>3.21.2</protoc.version>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>${protoc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>clean generate-sources compile install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
            <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <protocVersion>${protoc.version}</protocVersion>
                        <inputDirectories>
                            <include>src/main/resources</include>
                        </inputDirectories>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried many ways but couldn't find the error. Can you help find it? Note: I already created `org.abraxel.grpc` package. I'm using Mac OS with M1 chipset.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `protobuf-maven-plugin` [as described in the grpc-java README](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java#generated-code):

```
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.6.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.19.2:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
        <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
        <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.47.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

The `compile` goal generates protobuf messages and the `compile-custom` goal generates gRPC service stubs.

Comment: I just tried but unfortunately it doesn't work. That plugins maybe for windows, but I'm using MacOS

Comment: There are MacOS builds of protoc/protoc-gen-grpc-java as well. Are you on M1? You'll need Rosetta in that case. I'll note that the binaries are not signed.

Comment: Yes I'm using M1. How should i enable Rosetta for this case?

Comment: I'm not a Mac user. I've just heard that "install Rosetta and it starts working." And I tell other users to "install Rosetta" and they tend to know how to do that.